# How to kill all open terminals using command lines in CentOs

Tags: linux, terminal, centos

I'm using putty to connect to Centos and sometimes it disconnect, and the open terminals on centos stays open, is  there a way by a command line to close/kill all open terminals?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to kill all open terminals except for the current one, you can use

```
kill $(pgrep bash)
```

`pgrep bash` lists the pids of all the active terminals

if the terminals refuse to die, you can use

```
kill -9 $(pgrep bash)
```

the "-9" is used to send the SIGKILL Signal to the process

Answer (score 0):

if you are using linux then just find out the process id of the putty

use `ps -a` to get PID of process then use `kill PID`

on Windows:

```
Open the command prompt as the current user or as Administrator.
Type tasklist to see the list of running processes and their PIDs. ...
To kill a process by its PID, type the command: taskkill /F /PID pid_number.
To kill a process by its name, type the command taskkill /IM "process name" /F.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Identify processes

   ps -ef | grep -E 'ssh.*pts' | grep -v grep |awk -F" " '{print $2}'

The above script it will give you the PID of those ssh pst connections on your machine; then as Vikas said you can [kill](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) those processes, remember be aware by using the kill command.

NOTE: you can use the [last](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1.html) command where you can see a list of the current/olders session on your machine.

2. Kill processes

   kill -9 PID1 PID2 PID3

Answer (score 0):

Kill old login wit command:

```
pkill -o -u $USER sshd
```

You can use 'screen' program for reconnect from where your connection was lost.